# Inserting array of values into a table

Tags: ios, uitableview, insert

I've issue in inserting an array of values into a table.. I've to insert the array of contact details into the table.. That is, I've the list of first names in an variable, list of last names in a variable, etc.. likewise I've to 24 columns to be inserted..

It throws an exception saying:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[contactlist filepath]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa2af5b0' *** First throw call stack: (0x257e012 0x1e06e7e 0x26094bd 0x256dbbc 0x256d94e 0x4b613 0x4b551 0x190c589 0x190a652 0x190b89a 0x190a60d 0x190a785 0x1857a68 0x4a0911 0x49fbb3 0x4ddcda 0x25208fd 0x4de35c 0x4de2d5 0x3c8250 0x2501f3f 0x250196f 0x2524734 0x2523f44 0x2523e1b 0x2ad57e3 0x2ad5668 0xd4affc 0x254d 0x2475) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Can anyone help me out on this..?

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSError *error;
    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"json.... %@",json);


    id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

    NSLog(@"jsonObject=%@", jsonObject);

    NSArray *checkArray=[jsonObject valueForKey:@"ND"];



    cheDisk=[checkArray valueForKey:@"FN"];
    cheDisk1=[checkArray valueForKey:@"LN"];


    NSLog(@"FN =%@",cheDisk);
    NSLog(@"LN =%@",cheDisk1);

    fname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[cheDisk objectAtIndex:0]];
    lname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[cheDisk1 objectAtIndex:0]];

    [self insertData];

    [ContactTableview reloadData];

}

-(void)insertData

{
    if (sqlite3_open([[self filepath]UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *insertStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO pu_Contacts (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('%@', '%@')", fname, lname];

        char *error;
        sqlite3_exec(db, [insertStatement UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error)!= SQLITE_OK;

        sqlite3_close(db);

    }
}

+(NSString *) filepath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UWdatabase1.sql"];
 }
```

Comment: So what's the issue, `fname` and `lname` are not inserted into the table? what the `char *error` said? `NSLog` it to see what's going on.

Comment: Does *contactlist* have a method called `filepath`?

Comment: Yeah.. to get the file path.. i just didn't paste it here so reduce the code..

Comment: @ManojEllappan: Issue is with the the `filepath` method. Please paste the code

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with this code:

```
[self filepath]
```

You are defined the method as a `class method`, so you can't call it using `self`.

```
+(NSString *) filepath
```

**Solution 1:**

Change the call like `[contactlist filepath];` using the class name.

**Solution 2:**

Change the method to instance method, like:

```
- (NSString *) filepath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UWdatabase1.sql"];
}
```

Comment: Its not working though.. Can anyone put up your own code to implement this logic

Comment: @ManojEllappan: Now what is the issue ? Did you tried both solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

What's the class name? change `self` by the class name in order to call a class method: 
`if (sqlite3_open([[MyClassName filepath]UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)`